# Dockerized .net core app doesn't load on Azure

Tags: azure, docker, visual-studio-2017

trying the following steps

1. Create .NET core web application in VS2017
2. Added docker support via Right click > add > Docker Support
3. Publish to Azure App service (Linux) via Right click > Publish
4. Leave all to default values and publish
5. [Site](http://webapplication320170523011525.azurewebsites.net/) doesn't load

This is my dockerfile (didn't change anything)

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication3.dll"]
```

[image: Summary]

[image: Publish logs]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check configuration files, doing no change in them sounds like you missed something

Comment: Which config files? docker compose?

Comment: Are you using .NET Framework with .NET Core? Windows or Linux Container? Is 1.0 or 1.1? Is application published before you build the Dockerfile?

Comment: Maybe you could debug your docker, please refer to this [link](https://wannabeegeek.com/2016/12/16/debugging-asp-net-core-apps-running-in-docker-containers-using-vs-2017/).